# How to properly make an api request in python3 with base64 encoding

Tags: bash, api, python-3.x

I'm trying to run a bash script at server creation on vultr.com through the API using Python3

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The server starts up but the script never runs.

The documentation states it has to be a base64 encoded string. I'm thinking I'm doing something wrong with the encoding.

Have any ideas?

```
import base64
import requests



key = 'redacted'

squid = '''#!/bin/bash
touch test'''

squid_encoded = base64.b64encode(squid.encode())

payload = {'DCID': 1, 'VPSPLANID': 29, 'OSID': 215, 'userdata': squid_encoded}
headers = {'API-Key': key}


def vult_api_call():
    p = requests.post('https://api.vultr.com/v1/server/create', data=payload, headers=headers)
    print(p.status_code)
    print(p.text)


vult_api_call()
```

Comment: does the script works if you run it manually?

Comment: just a blind shot - does the script have executable bit set?

Answer (score 0):

The cloud-init userdata scripts can be tricky to troubleshoot. Looking at your `squid` script, it is missing the `#cloud-config` header. Vultr has a similar example in their [docs](https://www.vultr.com/docs/getting-started-with-cloud-init):

**Run a script after the system boots.**

```
#cloud-config
bootcmd:
 - "/bin/echo sample > /root/my_file.txt"
</pre>
```

Support for this can vary by operating system though. I would recommend using Vultr's startup script feature instead of cloud-init, as it works for every operating system. These are referenced in the Vultr API spec with `SCRIPTID`.

Also note that "bootcmd:" will run every time the instance boots. There is also "runcmd:", but I have seen compatibility issues with it on some Ubuntu distros on Vultr.